# Viewing an array and tuple in Xcode 6.3 Playground

Tags: arrays, xcode, tuples, swift-playground

Prior to Xcode 6.3 when I clicked the Quick Look icon on the left in Playground file, it showed the array along with item indexes. Now it shows only "X elements" text and nothing else. Same thing happened with tuples. It's quite annoying since not always all elements fit in the sidebar. How to fix this?

Comment: File a bug report with Apple: http://bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be happening with Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105). Occasionally I even get a blank Quicklook pane, so it seems there may be a bug with the Quicklook feature. I have submitted a bug report to Apple (21135520)